# Ubuntu 12.04 Google connection problem

Tags: 12.04, google

I have problem with connection to the Google services. Sometimes when I try to open a Google site or any site where there was a Google ad, Firefox says "Connection..." and nothing happens. Then, after some minutes, the following text appears: "The connection has timed out".

I tried to use the Chromium instead of Firefox, but it did not work. Other pages and Google on other computers (WinXP) in the local network are working, but on my computer (where I use Ubuntu) they work only after I restart the system.

I wonder why Ubuntu does this, and how can I solve it.
Thanks for the help.
Peter

P.S.: Sorry for my bad English, I am from Hungary, and I am learning the language.

Comment: Do you have any plugin installed into your browser to block ads? Something like adblock?

Comment: No, any plugin like this.

Comment: Google smtp services not working too. I try to send email with Thunderbird, and it cannot connect to smtp.googlemail.com.

Comment: Same problem here http://askubuntu.com/questions/315955/why-i-cant-access-google-products-like-google-com-and-youtube-com?noredirect=1#comment400061_315955
I reinstalled Ubuntu four times. The problem seemed to fixed after reinstalling. It came back some time later each time. It is not permanent, I mean some time pages loads normal. So annoying.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but I think we should try to check that the problem is browser independent. Could you try the following in a terminal ?

```
telnet accounts.google.com 80
```

If the connection to `accounts.google.com` establishes, enter :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

And end the line with two line breaks.

If the answer comes almost immediately (it should say `302 Moved` after the HTTP headers), then your computer is perfectly able of establishing a connection to the Google accounts services. If you get a timeout issue at this step, or before, then it is browser independent.

In this last case, I would recommend checking firewall and global network configuration. There's also the very unlikely case where your router has set up restrictions for your machine.