# Why I can't access google products like google.com and youtube.com?

Tags: 12.10, networking, 13.04, google, cookie

First youtube started not loading videos, then almost all google products had problem. I had 12.04 and 12.10 on Asus N56VM. There was that problem. Now I have 13.04 on same machine. It still is. I have chrome, chromium and firefox. There is no difference. İnternet is generally fine. The problem is only on google products.

[image]

[image]

Edit:

- Changing DNS not worked. I tried lots of DNS servers.
- I tried with 3 different ISPs.
- It is not a Flash Player issue I think, because the problem is on all of Google services (Gmail, Calendar, Maps), not only YouTube.
- Tried disabling hardware acceleration option on Flash Player.
- The problem is temporary. Some times Google.com, Gmail or Youtube work, some times not. Thus so difficult to track the problem.
- These are some links related to my question. It is the same problem and no answer.

  - [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=255434)
  - [Google locking on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313607/google-locking-on-ubuntu?rq=1)
  - [Strange networking problem. Google does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270273/strange-networking-problem-google-does-not-work?rq=1)
  - [Ubuntu 12.04 Google connection problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267891/ubuntu-12-04-google-connection-problem)

Edit 2: Question marked as duplicate. Okay, question is same (I noticed that when it marked, sorry). But the answer to that question is "change DNS" and I said it does not work for me.

Edit 3: I noticed that If I sing out from google account Youtube works well on all of my browsers(Chrome, Chromium, Firefox). I tried with different google accounts of mine on different browsers. Result is same. Finally I catch something to track this problem. If I'm signed in to google there is problem with google products.

Comment: Interesting. Can you please try setting your DNS server to ``8.8.8.8``? If you need help doing so, tell us.

Comment: Set your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and apply. This solution will work everywhere and you will always get the domain that you have chosen.

Comment: Domains have already setted to 8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.1 . I tried changing domains.

Comment: this has nothing to do with DNS as this 3 statements above. Webpage is correctly displayed...

Comment: Page loads immediately but 'related videos' previews on right column takes one - two minutes to show up. After three - five minutes, that error message shows up.

Comment: @Dee When a video is accessed on Youtube, there are accessed and others domains apart from youtube.com. you can see this in the bottom bar of the browser.

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is that your ISP is blocking streaming video. I see the exact same a lot on hotspots, 3G/mobile internet, etc. as being a policy of the internet service. Do you have another network/ISP you can connect the computer to and check again?

Comment: @Can Try 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, not 4.2.2.1. See https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Comment: @ Radu Rădeanu I tried lots of dns including openDns. 
@gertvdijk I tried with 3G now (via tethering - android). Result is same. Not loading.

Comment: I realized i have flash player plugin issue trough a virtual machine. Virtualised windows played flash video without any problem... but the linux You tube nothing. Try it trough minitube.

Comment: Could you try to disable Hardware Acceleration? Right-click in the video, select "Settings...", go to the first tab, untick the hardware acceleration setting.

Comment: @gertvdijk Tried. No change.

Comment: On Gmail I get this warning 'Something s not right.
We're having trouble contacting our servers. We're going to keep trying.'

Comment: These are some links related to my question. It is same problem and no answer.
[bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=255434) 
 [Google locking on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313607/google-locking-on-ubuntu?rq=1) 
 [Strange networking problem. Google does not work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270273/strange-networking-problem-google-does-not-work?rq=1)

Comment: have you tried removing unity-webapp-* and resetting allowed domains under dconf editor? if you want further details, let me know.

Comment: I could not find any unity-webapp. They are not installed. Allowed domains is empty.

Comment: Your fresh installed system should come with unity-webapps-common and unity-webapps-service, did you removed them?

Comment: Yes I find them now. I'm removing. That is an intermittent problem. Now everything is how it should be. I will test for a day. I will let you know if problem still exist or not.

Comment: Nope. It didn't work. Youtube videos still cant be loaded.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but your question appears to be off-topic because this is an issue with Google, reading your last update. *"I noticed that If I sing out from google account Youtube works well on all of my browsers [...] If I'm signed in to google there is problem with google products."* Get in contact with Google support to get this fixed - if Youtube is working while signed out this is not a Ubuntu issue. I'm not able to vote to close your question at this time, because you have put a bounty on it.

Comment: My computer dual booted. I used Win7 and Win8 alongside Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04. And I used different browsers on these OS's. 
On Windows, no cookie problem at all. On all version of Ubuntu, all of the browsers had problem with Google cookies. I mean, there might be something that Ubuntu related. However I gave bounty to best answer. Thanks. @gertvdijk

Comment: @Can Okay, clear. That statement makes quite some difference. I'd still ask Google how the combination of Ubuntu with being logged into your account makes the services unavailable to you.

Answer (score 3):

I had similiar problem with youtube videos not playing. I am using chrome browser mostly, so I will explain the method that fixed my problem.

1. Open the chrome settings
2. Open advanced settings.
3. On the Privacy section click content settings
4. Under the Cookies click the Manage exceptions and set www.youtube.com and youtube.com as blocked.

So the basically the problem is cookies. Above procedure solved my problem.

Comment: I tried with 3 different browser.

Comment: Sorry it didn't solve your issue. I thought we had the same problem. Blocking the cookies from youtube solved it for me. Maybe you can check your /etc/hosts file contains any entries related to google.com, youtube etc. If there are try to delete those and reboot the computer.

Comment: I checked hosts file. There is nothing about google our youtube. Thanks for your trying. This problem is really annoying. I'm afraid it will cause me to pass windows.

Comment: Hey you were right. It is cookie issue. Did you find a solution to use Youtube with signed in ?

Comment: I am glad it worked. I don't use youtube as signed in, so no solutions about it yet.

Comment: You could also try to remove all Google related cookies. Go in the similar menus search for `google.com` and `youtube.com` and remove all the cookies, local storage etc. there. Then you're logged out of Google and you can try to log in with "fresh cookies".

Comment: @Can, I have tried to login to youtube using chrome, but it failed and gave me the error **"There was an issue logging you into YouTube"**. This is probably happening due to blocked cookies from youtube.com in my chrome setting. Firefox did not give me any errors and I was able to login and watch some videos successfully  . (I didn't change any setting in Firefox)
As **gertvdijk** said, removing the google and youtube related cookies could solve your remaining problems.

Comment: When I remove cookies in 3 browser, Youtube works well. However when I try signing in(if I have not blocked cookies), Youtube doesn't load videos. If I block cookies, I can use all of Google products-which I love- as signed in and Youtube as signed out. 'Blocking youtube.com cookies' is the best solution I think. Thank you very much.